# run cases of log4net with UNnit, log file cannot be created. no error raised

Tags: .net, nunit, log4net

recently testing a loging project which used log4net(.NET), it's a console project. the log file can be created if run the project in VS, but log file canno be created if run the .exe file in NUnit. the log contents just be printed out in UNnit GUI. no error raise.
why that? I config the log4net in App.config.

---

I need use Nunit to testing this case.

---

I have googled, no answer worked.

---

my config file in App.config as follow:

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="WARN">
  </level>     
  <appender-ref ref="SystemLogFileAppender" />
</root>

<appender name="SystemLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="d:\" type="" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd_SYS.TXT" />
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />

  <Encoding value="UTF-8" />
  <layout type="Log.LogLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value=" Level: %property{Level}%n Message: %property   {Message}%n Exception: %property{Exception}%n CreateDate: %property{CreateDate}%n%n" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="Log.SystemLogFilter">
  </filter>
  </appender>
```

I added following code my project's AssemblyInfo.cs, not work:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```

Then, I changed it to the following, not work again :

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile=@"D:\LogTest\FrameworkTest.exe.config",Watch=true)]
```

Comment: You haven't given us *any* context about where you're trying to log to, or what your code looks like.

Comment: My Godess,dont mention that. I tried to paste my code and config file here. but I gave up finally after tried to submit answer many times. stackoverflow was to strict for code style.

Comment: i will put my code here later.

Answer (score 1):

no error raise: If log4net can't log or the logging information is not found or the log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator is not configured in the dll, log4net will not log and raise no error. Is because logging should not influence you program.

If no log is written, you probably have a configuration problem. The logging has to be configured in the run directory of NUnit. You should deploy the log4net.config with your binary files and add the attribute to your test project (for logging in your test project):

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Comment: yes, i think it's problem of my configuration. I have done following action: (1)put the config file in target project(it's a library project, which referenced log4net),log cannot be writen.(2)put the config file in test project(it's a console project, which reference the target project's dll, will be run with NUnit), log cannot be written. Finnaly i upgrade my NUnit to 2.6(the latest version). resovled!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I update the NUnit to version2.6.2, then worked. with the config:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```